# How to use TFormatSettings.Create without being specific to a platform?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have the following in Delphi XE:

```
fSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT);
```

But I always get a warning on compile:

```
W1002 Symbol 'Create' is specific to a platform
```

What is the correct way to do this, so that I do not get a warning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two options

1) Use the overload version which uses a string instead of a [`TLocaleID`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TLocaleID)

```
class function Create(const LocaleName: string): TFormatSettings; overload; static;
```

2) Disable the warning locally

```
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
    fSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT);
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM ON}
```

Comment: Option 3. Disable the warning globally. If you never build for platforms other than Windows, there's not much point in enabling it at all.

Comment: If I choose to use the string version, what is the string that is equivalent to LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT?

Comment: try using an empty string or the constructor without parameters, this will call the [GetThreadLocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function internally. just be careful with the calls to `SetThreadLocale` because can change the result of this function.

Answer (score 2):

There are different overloads of `TFormatSettings.Create`. The one with an LCID is specific to Windows. The one without any parameters and the one taking a locale name as a string are more portable.

Or you could suppress the warning for platform-specific units and procedures, if you know your software will never be used for anything other than Delphi for Windows. The VCL contains traces of now unsupported platforms such as Linux (Kylix) and .NET (Delphi.NET), and since they're as dead as can be, making your code portable to those platforms may be a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

My code is now written as follows:

```
{$IFDEF VER220}
    FormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(GetThreadLocale);
{$ELSE}
    GetLocaleFormatSettings(GetThreadLocale, FormatSettings);
{$ENDIF}
```

You will probably want to adjust that IFDEF for appropriate future versions, but it gives the idea.

Comment: This snippet actually is by magnitude more specific to platform than which compiler complains about.

Comment: @user539484 Perhaps, but IIRC I got it from the help as the recommended way.